# Wireless not working

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, internet

My internet worked perfectly fine until my rabbit jumped on my laptop, and I assume switched something and now my internet won't connect. I have has this happen before are just resolved it by hitting fn f4 but for some reason that's not working!! I have a dell XPS using windows 7! Please help

Comment: What's the exact model and serial number of the rabbit?

Comment: @smc You're the first troll I've ever seen on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Could you provide additional details as to what else you have tried to fix this problem? Have you tried resetting the router? etc etc etc | @smc very good :D

Answer (score 1):

You normally have a few places that WiFi can be disabled:

Go to control panel > Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings > Check Wireless Adapter is not disabled if so right click enable

Your function key to disable 'on the fly' as you mentioned like function key & F4, etc.

A physical button somewhere either down the sides or on the front of the laptop which can toggle Wireless on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried Fn+F4? The Fn key is usually blue and close to the space bar, if this does not work than maybe your wireless card has become disconnected, in that case it should be easy enough for you to fix just look under you laptop where your battery, Ramm, and HDD are and you should see a wifi symbol or something similar, open that up and see if the two wire have become disconnected, it might be a software issue but i have a hunch it is hardware.

hope this helps

Comment: The OP has stated he has tried Fn F4...